# What are the Azure Data Factory Thumbling Window trigger limitations?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a Multiple pipelines dependent on each other, I want to use Thumbling window trigger, Requesting you to suggested, Is it right approach? Are there any limitations using Thumbling window trigger?

Regards,
Ashok

Answer (score 0):

Tumbling window trigger is a more heavy weight alternative for schedule trigger offering a suite of features for complex scenarios(dependency on other tumbling window triggers, rerunning a failed job and set user retry for pipelines).--MSFT documentation

Limitation:
A tumbling window trigger has a one-to-one relationship with a pipeline and can only reference a singular pipeline.

If one of the dependencies triggers fails, you must successfully rerun it in order for the dependent trigger to run.

A tumbling window trigger will wait on dependencies for seven days before timing out. After seven days, the trigger run will fail